# vtkLookupTable specifing colors with opacities

Tags: vtk, lookup-tables

I am trying to use a vtkLookupTable in order to set the colors for my mesh. I started with vtkColorTransferFunction which worked fined except that it does not enable me to set opacities for various colors. 
vtkLookupTable offers this opportunity, but I am having problems to get it working.

My vtkPolyData have scalars value set that determine the color they shall get. Overall 7 values, set with the scalars 0 to 6.

My vtkLookupTable looks like this:

```
vtkLookupTable lut = new vtkLookupTable();
    lut.SetNumberOfColors(7);
    double opacity = 0.3;
    lut.SetTableValue(0, 0, 0, 1, opacity);
    lut.SetTableValue(1, 0, 1.0, 0, opacity);
    lut.SetTableValue(2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.0, opacity);
    lut.SetTableValue(3, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.7);
    lut.SetTableValue(4, 1.0, 0.8, 0.0, opacity);
    lut.SetTableValue(5, 1.0, 0.4, 0.0, opacity);
    lut.SetTableValue(6, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
```

If I use a vtkColorTransferFunction with the same values (just no opacity) it works. Anyone any idea why this is not working? I should be same?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

From your pseudocode, two lines may be missing.

```
     lut.SetTableRange(0.0,6.0)
     lut.Build()
```

Do you call these functions?

If it is not this problem then it may be because of the polydatamapper you are using. Can you submit a whole pipeline for your problem?

As a guide the following code will need to be called to allow your scalar values to be 
added to the mapper and visualised correctly.

```
    mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
    mapper.SetScalarVisibility(1)
    mapper.SetScalarRange(0.0,6.0)
```